# Axios Paypal Token Issue

Tags: ajax, curl, paypal, token, axios

As a precursor I don't understand why if the token expires one would want to use CURL or Postman to get the token rather than a ajax call that would continously get the updated token before sending payment.

Anyway I was able to use Postman to get a token, but I have tried several axios requests with none successfully obtaining a token. I am getting a 401 unauthorized error. My understanding is by using auth: { username: '', password: '' } that it enables basic auth. My axios attempt is below however instead of empty strings I have strings of my client id and secret. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
axios.post('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token', {
  grant_type: 'client_credentials',
  auth: {username: '',
    password: ''
  },
  headers:{
    'Content-Type':'x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }}
).then((result)=>{
    console.log('resultis',result)
  }).catch((err)=>{console.log("err",err)})
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but it may help others

```
axios({
method: "post",
url: "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token",
header: {
    'Accept': 'application/json', 
    'Accept-Language': 'en_US',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 
},
data: 'grant_type=client_credentials',
auth: {
    username: "PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID",
    password: "PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET"
}
}).then(response => {
}).catch(error => {})
```

Answer (score -1):

One easy solution is to use the node SDK rather than actaully making the HTTP request yourself.